# Can I use BSDF for the emission pattern of a lamp or light source?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

I started to study blender because I want to perform some simulations on bicycle lighting.

My goal is to take a picture of a beam pattern against a wall, then use it as the Bidirectional EMISSION Distribution Function for the light source, rendering its illumination pattern when actually used along a road or other outdoor environment.

For example, a typical distribution for a vehicular headlight is as follows:

[image]

Then, I would create a light source with this custom emission pattern (sort of an "UV map" for luminous emission intensity) to render images such as these, with a fair amount of realism (I don't plan to get state-of-the art, 100% physically accurate simulation):

[image]

So my questions are:

> - Is it possible to do shuch a thing in Blender?
> - If it is, which concepts should I look for?

I plan to use Cycles rendering engine.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://www.blendernation.com/2013/01/29/add-on-ies-files-in-cycles/)

Comment: @gandalf3 that is very interesting, but I think I still have a lot to learn before making it work... Thank you for now, I'll surely take a deeper look as soon as I can!

Answer (score 3):

Spot into textured transparent shader will work. like this

[image]

Shader

[image]

Comment: That's interesting... Since I won't model the headlamp reflector anyway, I think anything that gives the radiation distribution is fine. Although there is a suggestion to use actual .IES files (which I don't have anyway), the possibility to use plain old PNG is yet more attractive. Gonna try it this weekend, thanks!!

Comment: I have studied what I could in the weekend, and came to the point where I have the textured road, the cameras and the light source (I am using spotlight). But the images you posted ended up a bit too small, so I would like to ask what I should do from now, to make a scene like yours? Which concepts/panels/properties should I use? What is a "shader" supposed to be and how do I create one like yours?

Comment: Apply your texture to the plane, select use nodes in node editor window. Select transparent shader. pipe texture as in the picture I posted. You can scale the plane in which you applied your image to adjust the size of the projection.

Comment: Ok, after a lot of tinkering I figured it out and gonna put some feedback as soon as I have a good-looking result. One last question: I noticed this works in Cycles, but not in Blender Render. Do you know if this is possible in Blender Render, or something similar to it?